# Why is the AppMaker console not appearing in preview mode?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've been working on an AppMaker project for about a week, and starting today the console that usually appears at the bottom of the window is missing when I enter preview mode.

I've checked the URL and the "Console=1" parameter is there. Changing the value to a 0, and back again has no effect.

Is there a common cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is probably just resized down to the bottom of the window so you can't see it (it remembers the position from previous sessions). If you can't grab the handle near the bottom of the screen to enlarge it you can follow these instructions (in Chrome):

1. Right click on the App Maker page and click inspect.
2. In the panel that pops up, click on the Console tab.
3. Paste this code into the console and hit enter.

   ```
   var console = app.currentPage.getElement().parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children;
   console.item(1).style.bottom = '159px';
   console.item(2).style.bottom = '163px';
   console.item(3).style.height = '159px';
   ```

That should resize the App Maker console back to it's default position.

Comment: Well, now don't I feel dumb. It was sized down so small it was indistinguishable from the bottom of the window. Thanks for the supremely helpful answer!